# Jasmine tests AngularJS Directives with templateUrl

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-directive

I'm writing directive tests for AngularJS with Jasmine, and using templateUrl with them: https://gist.github.com/tanepiper/62bd10125e8408def5cc

However, when I run the test I get the error included in the gist:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET views/currency-select.html
```

From what I've read in the docs I thought I was doing this correctly, but it doesn't seem so - what am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214760/unit-testing-angularjs-directive-with-templateurl/16528985#16528985

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### If you're using ngMockE2E or ngMock:

*all* HTTP requests are processed locally using rules you specify and *none* are passed to the server. Since templates are requested via HTTP, they too are processed locally. Since you did not specify anything to do when your app tries to connect to `views/currency-select.html`, it tells you it doesn't know how to handle it. You can easily tell ngMockE2E to pass along your template request:

```js
$httpBackend.whenGET('views/currency-select.html').passThrough();
```

Remember that you can also use regular expressions in your routing paths to pass through all templates if you'd like.

The docs discuss this in more detail: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend

#### Otherwise use this:

You'll need to use the `$injector` to access the new backend. From the linked docs:

```js
var $httpBackend;
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  $httpBackend.whenGET('views/currency-select.html').respond(200, '');
}));
```

Comment: Hmm, I've given this a try but it seems that after I inject it, passThrough is not available as a function:  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/currency-select.html').passThrough()')  I've also included beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E')); at the top of my file and it goes back to the original error

Comment: There is no passThrough() method in a $httpBackend Mock. Its says it right in the docs. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend Thats why your getting the function not available error. Now if you want to mock this in the frontend and the in unit testing you have the passThrough method available - just not in unit testing...

Comment: @StenMuchow My answer and @tanepiper's problem are not for the `ngMock` module, but the [`ngMockE2E`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) module, which *does* support the `passThrough()`. Typically, one wouldn't use it during unit tests because unit tests shouldn't need any HTTP requests like templates, but in the case that they do and the build does not compile them, the E2E backend can be used.

Comment: @StenMuchow The answer linked to the correct page of the documentation, but to avoid future confusion I removed the part that confused you.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller pretty sure passThrough() is deprecated, but this solution is still not complete. One must actually use ngHtml2JsPreprocessor and set the path to the sample path as the templateUrl in the directive.

Comment: @cameronjroe I'm still unsure what you're trying to accomplish. According to the docs, `passThrough()` is not deprecated. I'm not sure why one would need to use a pre-processor to accomplish this; the OP simply wanted the XHR to go through to his backend to deliver the template for use during unit testing. Based on my understanding, `passThrough()` does precisely that. Can you provide an example or some documentation to indicate otherwise?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller you are correct in ngMockE2E this works, but not in ngMock. I prefer to use the pre-processor so that I can use external templates as modules, but you can change it back. I wasn't aware of the ngMockE2E modules. Apologies.

Comment: Use `beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'));` in order to get `passThrough()`.

Answer (score 20):

the Karma way is to load the template html dynamically into $templateCache. you could just use html2js karma pre-processor, as explained [here](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing/blob/master/test/tabsSpec.js)

this boils down to adding templates '*.html' to your files in the conf.js file
as well 
preprocessors = {
  '*.html': 'html2js'
};

and use

```
beforeEach(module('..'));

beforeEach(module('...html', '...html'));
```

into your js testing file

Comment: Here's a fairly good explanation how the templateCache-way works: http://www.portlandwebworks.com/blog/testing-angularjs-directives-handling-external-templates. Just note that the blog speaks about a fairly old version of Karma, so today you'd need to use ng-html2js instead of html2js for preprocessing the templates to js.

Answer (score 6):

If this is a unit-test, you won't have access to `$httpBackend.passthrough()`. That's only available in ngMock2E2, for end-to-end testing. I agree with the answers involving `ng-html2js` (used to be named html2js) but I would like to expand on them to provide a full solution here.

To render your directive, Angular uses `$http.get()` to fetch your template from `templateUrl`. Because this is unit-testing and `angular-mocks` is loaded, `angular-mocks` intercepts the call to `$http.get()` and give you the `Unexpected request: GET` error. You can try to find ways to by pass this, but it's much simpler to just use angular's `$templateCache` to preload your templates. This way, `$http.get()` won't even be an issue.

That's what the [ng-html2js preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) do for you. To put it to work, first install it:

```
$ npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor --save-dev
```

Then configure it by adding/updating the following fields in your `karma.conf.js`

```
{
    files: [
      //
      // all your other files
      //

      //your htmp templates, assuming they're all under the templates dir
      'templates/**/*.html'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        //
        // your other preprocessors
        //

        //
        // tell karma to use the ng-html2js preprocessor
        "templates/**/*.html": "ng-html2js"
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        //
        // Make up a module name to contain your templates.
        // We will use this name in the jasmine test code.
        // For advanced configs, see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
        moduleName: 'test-templates',
    }
}
```

Finally, in your test code, use the `test-templates` module that you've just created. Just add `test-templates` to the module call that you typically make in `beforeEach`, like this:

```
beforeEach(module('myapp', 'test-templates'));
```

It should be smooth sailing from here on out. For a more in depth look at this and other directive testing scenarios, check out [this post](http://taivo.github.io/guides/unit-testing-angular-directives)

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps get the `$templatecache` from the injector and then do something like

```
$templateCache.put("views/currency-select.html","<div.....>");
```

where in place of `<div.....>` you would be putting your template.

After that you setup your directive and it should work just fine!

Comment: I went with something similar using $httpBackend doing $httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/currency-select.html').respond('<select ng-options="currency.name for currency in currencies" ng-model="selected_currency"></select>'); - however it kind of defeats DRY - I want it to load my templates, not have to repeat them in code again.

Comment: Not great for long HTML templates but it gets me past where I've been stuck for a good few hours! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If this is still not working , use fiddler to see the content of the js file dynamically generated by htmltojs processor and check the path of template file.

It should be something like this

```
angular.module('app/templates/yourtemplate.html', []).run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('app/templates/yourtemplate.html',
```

In my case , it was not same as I had in my actual directive which was causing the issue.

Having the templateURL exactly same in all places got me through.

Comment: having the file paths different was causing this error for me

Answer (score 4):

As requested, converting a comment to an answer.

---

For the people who want to make use of @Lior's answer in **Yeoman** apps:

Sometimes the way the templates are referenced in karma config and consequently - the names of modules produced by `ng-html2js` don't match the values specified as `templateUrl`s in directive definitions.
You will need adjusting generated module names to match `templateUrl`s.
These might be helpful:

- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor#configuration
- gist: https://gist.github.com/vucalur/7238489

Answer (score 2):

this is example how to test directive that use partial as a templateUrl

```
describe('with directive', function(){
  var scope,
    compile,
    element;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));//myApp module

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache){
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   compile = $compile;

   $templateCache.put('view/url.html',
     '<ul><li>{{ foo }}</li>' +
     '<li>{{ bar }}</li>' +
     '<li>{{ baz }}</li>' +
     '</ul>');
   scope.template = {
     url: 'view/url.html'
    };

   scope.foo = 'foo';
   scope.bar = 'bar';
   scope.baz = 'baz';
   scope.$digest();

   element = compile(angular.element(
    '<section>' +
      '<div ng-include="template.url" with="{foo : foo, bar : bar, baz : baz}"></div>' +
      '<div ng-include="template.url" with=""></div>' +
    '</section>'
     ))(scope);
   scope.$digest();

 }));

  it('should copy scope parameters to ngInclude partial', function(){
    var isolateScope = element.find('div').eq(0).scope();
    expect(isolateScope.foo).toBeDefined();
    expect(isolateScope.bar).toBeDefined();
    expect(isolateScope.baz).toBeDefined();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [jasmine-maven-plugin](https://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/) together with RequireJS you can use the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) to load the template content into a variable and then put it in the template cache.

```
define(['angular', 'text!path/to/template.html', 'angular-route', 'angular-mocks'], function(ng, directiveTemplate) {
    "use strict";

    describe('Directive TestSuite', function () {

        beforeEach(inject(function( $templateCache) {
            $templateCache.put("path/to/template.html", directiveTemplate);
        }));

    });
});
```