# How can I test a directive using templateUrl in Chutzpah's headless browser

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

Does anyone know how to get a headless browser like Chutzpah's Visual Studio Test Adapter to allow a directive to access its .html template file? Chutzpah uses PhantomJS for a headless browser which appears to limit my options.

I'm using Chutzpah Test Adapter 2.5 and AngularJS 1.2.0-r.2.

I get the error:

> Unexpected request: GET myApp/directives/template.html

Which is caused by Angular attempting to use the $http service to access my directive's template.

I've found a few different workarounds:

1. [Manually using XMLHttpRequest to import the templates.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368287/545680)
2. [Using a utility like Grunt to inline the template into your directive's JS code.](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing)
3. `$httpBackend.when('GET', 'myApp/directives/template.html').passThrough()` - this only works in e2e tests, not unit tests.
4. [Put the template directly into the test code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15231422/545680)

None of these options particularly satisfy me. I'd prefer to be able to let the directive load its template transparently so I can test it as a component. Is there a way I can get this scenario working?

Example code:

```
angular.module('myDirective', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'myApp/directives/template.html',
        // Some other options, omitted for brevity.
    };
});
```

template.html:

```
<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>
```

Example Jasmine test:

```
describe('myDirective', function() {
    // Assign $scope using inject(), load module etc.
    // Insert workaround for $httpBackend loading my templateUrl here.
    it('should transclude content', function() {
        var element = $compile("<my-directive>Look Mom, I'm in my directive!</my-directive>")($scope);
        $scope.$digest();

        expect(element.text().trim()).toBe("Look Mom, I'm in my directive!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, please! Option #3 should not be banned in unit tests, it adds complication. The `ng-html2js` option sounds functional, but I don't want a build step in front of my unit tests.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. You load `ngHtml2Js` as a preprocessor in Karma, so it doesn't complicate the test run, only the configuration. This is the way to go for testing directives with `templateUrl`s on `Karma`

Comment: I've also gone with Karma and `ngHtml2Js` as that's where the test stack appears the most mature. This doesn't address the original question of getting it to work in Chutzpah though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working, using Chutzpah's **compile** option. I ported [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) into a PowerShell script and then call that from Chutzpah to compile the HTML into JS files.

Added PowerShell script next to chutzpah.json settings file (the below script contains untested support for PreprendPrefix and StripSuffix)

```
# PowerShell port of https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor

Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Path,
    [string] $Module = '',
    [string] $StripPrefix = '',
    [string] $PrependPrefix = '',
    [string] $StripSuffix = ''
)

Function EscapeContent($content) {
    $content -replace "\\", "\\\\" -replace "'", "\'" -replace  "`r?`n", "\n' +`n    '"
}

Function Rename($fileName) {
    "$PrependPrefix" + ("$fileName" -replace "$StripPrefix", '' -replace "$StripSuffix", '' -replace "\\", "/")
}

$Template = If ("$Module" -eq "") {
    "angular.module('{0}', []).run(function(`$templateCache) {{`n" `
      + "  `$templateCache.put('{0}',`n    '{2}');`n" `
      + "}});`n"
  } Else {
    "(function(module) {{`n" `
        + "try {{`n" `
        + "  module = angular.module('{1}');`n" `
        + "}} catch (e) {{`n" `
        + "  module = angular.module('{1}', []);`n" `
        + "}}`n" `
        + "module.run(function(`$templateCache) {{`n" `
        + "  `$templateCache.put('{0}',`n    '{2}');`n" `
        + "}});`n" `
        + "}})();`n"
  }

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Filter *.html | Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String
    $content = EscapeContent $content
    $fileName = Rename "$($_.FullName)"
    ("$Template" -f "$fileName", "$Module", "$content") | Set-Content "$($_.FullName).js"
}
```

Added **compile** configuration to chutzpah.json and add the "compiled" JS files to References (the reference could added from the test file, but I prefer to use chutzpah.json to manage all the references)

```
{
    "References": [
        { "Path": "./path/to/templates/", "Include": "*.html.js" },
    ],
    "Compile": {
        "Extensions": [".html"],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [".html.js"],
        "SourceDirectory": "./path/to/templates",
        "OutDirectory": "./path/to/templates",
        "Executable": "%powershellexe%",
        "Arguments": "-NoProfile %chutzpahsettingsdir%\\chutzpah-ng-html2js-compiler.ps1 -Path '/path/to/templates/' -Module 'templates' -StripPrefix '.+(?=\\\\templates)'"
    }
}
```

In your test files, load the module, in my case they are all in 'templates' module

```
beforeEach(module('templates'));
// or alternatively
beforeEach(module('/path/to/templates/foo.html'));
```

Comment: I should point out, this does leave the extra .html.js files behind, but I just added an ignore file to hide them from source control.

Comment: Nice work - I was unaware of the compile option. How long has it been around?

Comment: How did you get around the "powershellScript.ps1 cannot be loaded because running 
scripts is disabled on this system" ?

Comment: @shieldstroy That's a PowerShell security error. You need to set the execution policy https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx

Comment: I did change it so that I could run the script manually, but chutzpah is still giving me that error. I'm also worried about requiring every other person on my team to have to change their security settings too. Typical windows amirite? Anyways, I found a simpler solution (the <template ...> answer from squadwuschel) that suits my needs and doesn't requiring running this script.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the "template" Reference from Chutzpah

http://matthewmanela.com/blog/chutzpah-2-4-2/

```
/// <template path="../../MvcAngularJs1_3/ScriptsApp/directives/Templates/testTemplate.html" />
/// <reference path="../../mvcangularjs1_3/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" />
/// <reference path="../../mvcangularjs1_3/scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../mvcangularjs1_3/scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
...
```

under the references, then Chutzpah includes the HTML directly in the Test HTML File. I've given my Templates a unique css Class to find them and put them by hand into the Template AngularJS Template Cache.

my HTML Template

```
<div class="row templateTestTemplate">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
       <h1>Tempalte Test</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

the directive

```
angular.module("testTemplateDirective", [])
    .directive("testTemplate", function() {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           replace: true,
           templateUrl: 'ScriptsApp/directives/Templates/testTemplate.html'
       }
});
```

in my unit Tests I am using jQuery to find the Template and add it to the Template Cache. Angular firsts looks in the Template Cache and don't makes an HTTP call.

```
var template = jQuery(".templateTestTemplate")[0].outerHTML;
$templateCache.put("ScriptsApp/directives/Templates/testTemplate.html", template);
```

that works Great so far, but only works with chutzpah, when you run this Test with Resharper the test will fail, because resharper does not copy the template into the Test HTML.

I've also opend a request on the Chutzpah GitHub Page to surround the HTML with Script Tags and an ID so that you don't need to extend the Template 
https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/330

Comment: Thank you for making sure my afternoon wasn't a complete waste. This solved it for me.

Comment: Has this been solved where you don't have to modify the template to support the unit test?

Comment: Yes in the newest Version its Supported, you don't need to modify your Templates anymore

Comment: It render html content in my test. any idea to stop render this?

Comment: Yes look in the documentation from cutzhpah it supports now adding your template to Script Tags, but this needs special configuration and cutzpah references in your Test

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue trying to test my directives.  I found a solution using the pattern from
https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing.

Step 1: use ng-html2js plugin to compile angular template into javascript
Step 2: do like the previous answered replied and include it as a module in your before each.

ng-html2js also allows you to perform custom manipulation of the 'url' that it expects which could be helpful if your test directory is not the same as your app directory.

Comment: Hi, your answer sounds like it is using Karma and NodeJS, rather than Chutzpah, which was the original question. ng-html2js or another pre-processor would definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using ng-html2js this is a great video that shows how to get it all setup to test the templateUrl directive. I am not sure how applicable this is to Chutzpah as this is a Karma example, but it might get ya in the right direction!

https://vimeo.com/90876119

Answer (score 0):

You can use jasmine-jquery to load content from file or http into $templateCache. It works in Chutzpah without any modifications.

First add jasmine-jquery to your project and add in chutzpah.json References:

(from my code)

```
"References" : [
    {"Path" : "vendor/jasmine-jquery-2.1.0.js"}
]
```

Then in your test, inject $templateCache and load it with "live" content via jasmine.getFixtures() like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache) {
    //Loading template from live develop server
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "http://localhost:47152";
    var templateUrl = "/myApp/directives/template.html";
    $templateCache.put(templateUrl, jasmine.getFixtures()  
        .getFixtureHtml_(templateUrl));
}));
```

If you load via http and use Chrome for your tests, you must add CORS support on the server.

Comment: Yes, you need to add CORS support on the server (as stated). Does that fix it?

Comment: I had to check by disabling browser security. In test explorer window of VS, it runs without error.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you include your template into your injector before it gets created. So try,

```
beforeEach(module('myApp/directives/template.html');
```