# How can I test a directive using templateUrl in Chutzpah in VS 2012

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012, angularjs-directive, chutzpah

How to include  templateURL in angular directive testing with Jasmine. I know there is way with karma but i am not using Karma . So any specific way of doing this?

Comment: If you are not using Karma, what testing framework are you using? It is all up to the framework being used

Comment: I have been through the same with chutzpah.. I could do it only by creating a wrapper for XMlHtppRequest and load the template and cache it.

Comment: I am using Jasmine with chutzpah extension in VS for unit testing and protractor for e2e Testing.

Comment: @PSL so there is nothing like adding  <templatepath> as a reference in testSpec? as per mentioned on Chuzpah's site help ?

Comment: @future I think that is for loading html templates, but in the case where we want to test directives or something with templateUrl it had to be in the angular templatecache... Atleast, i could not get it to work, so had to create a utility myself.. But i am alse eager to see if we get an answer to your question that has a better solution...

Comment: Can you file an issue and attach a repro of this scenario at https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah. I will then take a look and see if I can add anything to Chutzpah to make this easier/better.

Comment: @PSL   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645708/template-url-directive-unit-testing-without-karma
 how to create wrapper for XMIHttp and cache the template ?

Comment: @future That is exactly i am also doing now. Probably might switch back to karma.. :( Is it not working for you?

Comment: Nops :/ Karma not approved by my company's Baap TEAM...LOL(No other Option)

Comment: I got this working, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28554489/11019

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test a directive using templateUrl in Chutzpah's headless browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313645/how-can-i-test-a-directive-using-templateurl-in-chutzpahs-headless-browser)