# Template-Url Directive Unit Testing without Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine

**SOLUTION** = [Solution Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LxMHu7FGSHrh87MqXPwU?p=preview)

I have tried manually passing the template in testing - is it even good way of doing it ? How to make it passes !!!!!!!

How to write unit test for Simple directive with template-Url without Using Karma . I have tried following after seeing examples on stack-overflow but no success.

Directive

```
 app.directive("crazy", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl:"directivetemplate.html"
    };
});
```

Spec

```
   describe('Directive: crazy', function () {
   beforeEach(module('plunker'));

 beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache) {
var directiveTemplate = null;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function() {
    directiveTemplate = this.responseText;
};
req.open("get", "directivetemplate.html", false);
req.send();
$templateCache.put("directiveTemplate.html", directiveTemplate);

 }));

 it('should exist', inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
element = angular.element('<div crazy></div>');
element = $compile(element)($rootScope);
$rootScope.$apply();
expect(element.children().length.toBe(2));
 }));
 });
```

Comment: Is it hitting the onload? is the call sucess, probably cross verify the path. It needs to be relative from the place of your spec.

Comment: NoPS. Giving unexpected Get  :/

Comment: Anyways. finally got it :)