# How do I stop AngularJS app config blocks from running in my directive unit tests with a templateUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template, karma-jasmine

I've seen similar questions asked, but not one of them resolves the root of the problem, which assumes the following:

1. I can't use `whenGET('').passThrough()`, because I'm not using [ngMockE2E](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend).
2. I shouldn't need to use [ngMockE2E](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend) because I'm writing a unit test for a directive that literally does nothing but spit out "bar".
3. One suggestion was to [use a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214760/unit-testing-angularjs-directive-with-templateurl#answer-16528985) to serve-up these HTTP responses, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of a unit test?

Now, let me show you my directive:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('foo', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'templates/bar.html'
    };
  });
```

And here is the unit test:

```
describe('Directive: foo', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $compile;
  var $rootScope;
  var $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, $injector) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should be bar', inject(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('templates/bar.html', 'bar');
    var element = $compile('<div data-foo></div>')($rootScope);

    //$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/translations\//).passThrough(); // doesn't work
    $httpBackend.expectGET(/\/translations\//).respond('201', ''); // works
    $rootScope.$digest();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(element.text()).toBe('bar'); // works
  }));
});
```

Now, the test works just fine with all this bogus `$httpBackend` business in there, but this totally doesn't belong in my unit tests! How do I pull this `$httpBackend` crap out and stop the AngularJS app config blocks from running in my directive unit tests with a templateUrl?

*Note: This only happens when there is a templateUrl in the directive.*

BTW, the code that's triggering this HTTP request in the app config block is:

```
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('index');
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
  urlTemplate: '/translations/{part}/{lang}.json'
});
```

But I don't think that's necessarily relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your directives into their own module and include that module into your main app module. Then you can test your directive module without loading up your app module.

e.g.

```
angular.module('app-directives', [])
  .directive('foo', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'templates/bar.html'
    };
  });

angular.module('app', ['app-directives'])
  //Run your config stuff here
```