# How to access controllerAs namespace in unit test with compiled element?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, directive

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FlavorScape/fp1kktt9/ i try to set properties on the controller, not the $scope directly. In the template (in production) we just do myAliasCtrl.somePropertyList and the ng-repeat works.

However, this does not work in testing. I don't know how to get/assign the property on the controller.

**UPDATE:** 
I must have had some weird localized issue in my testing environment, because i do get ng-repeat to work. notice how there's two child elements, even though the property is on the aliased controller. http://jsfiddle.net/FlavorScape/2adn983y/2/

**however, my question still is, how would I get a reference to that compiled controller to say, create a spy?** (Or just get the reference to the aliased controller)?

Here's the source:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myTestDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myBinding: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-if="isRendered">TEST<div ng-repeat="foo in myCtrl.fooList">{{foo}}</div></div>',
        controller: 'myTestController',
        controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
    };
})
.controller('myTestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.isRendered = true;
     // if i reference this, ng-repeat works
    $scope.fooList = ["boob","cat", "Tesla"];
});

describe('myTest directive:', function () {
    var scope, compile, validHTML;

    validHTML = '<div><my-test-directive my-binding="isRendered"></my-test-directive></div>'; //i

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();        
        scope.isRendered = true;

        compile = $compile;
    }));

    function create() {
        var elem, compiledElem;
        elem = angular.element(validHTML);
        compiledElem = compile(elem)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        return compiledElem;    
    }

    it('should have a scope on root element', function () {  
        var el = create();

        // how to get the controller???
        el.scope().myCtrl.fooList =  ["monkey","apple","Dishwasher"];

        // notice it just has <!-- ng-repeat
        console.log( el );


        expect(el.text()).toContain('TEST');

    });
});
```

Comment: Additionally, how do i even access myCtrl instance, to say, add a spy?

Comment: actually, you'll notice it "compiles", but the controller never sets isRendered property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything works as expected :) You are just trying to access the wrong scope.

Because `ngIf` creates a new scope, you should access that scope (because `isRendered` is created on that child scope:

```
expect(el.children().first().scope().isRendered).toBeTruthy();
```

---

Here is the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fp1kktt9/2/)**.

---

**UPDATE:**

You are using `controllerAs`, basically you get the controller's `this` bound to a scope property. E.g. `controllerAs: 'myTestCtrl'` implicitly results to `$scope.myTestCtrl = this;` (where `this` is the controller instance.

But again you where trying to access the wrong element. You need the first child-element of the wrapping `<div>` and then you need its isolate scope (not normal scope):

```
var ctrl = el.children().first().isolateScope().myTestCtrl;
```

**[Another updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2adn983y/3/)**

Comment: As per the original question, I think it is best to avoid iterating on someCtrl.someList (i.e. controllerAs) in the template-- also, one has to define anything accessible by the view on the $scope, not the controller. It works fine for production, but it's impossible to test. One of those 1st time using Angular forehead smashes.

Comment: Who said it's impossible to test ? Agngular is all about testing. Everything is testable (and easily so) !

Comment: So how would you get an aliased controller (controllerAs) reference from a directive compiled during unit testing? I have found no such way, which is why I had to redefine data/functions on $scope. it is impossible to test an aliased controller + template.

Comment: I added a new fiddle to my question: how to get the controller ref?

Comment: I realized you answered why my test failed, but not my original question =)