# Unexpected request: POST no more request expected, after injecting directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

I am injecting a directive to test like the answer here: [How do I test the HTML pointed to by the templateUrl of an angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023581/how-do-i-test-the-html-pointed-to-by-the-templateurl-of-an-angular-directive)

```
describe('MyAppTest', function() {
    let elem;
    let scope;

    beforeEach(module('my.app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        elem = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')(scope)[0];
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('Should success', function () {
        expect(elem.getElementById('some-id').childElementCount.not.toBe(0);
    };
}
```

While I debug it the `elem` variable actually get my wanted directive but for some reason the test throw me this error: `Unexpected request: POST no more request expected`.

The `some-id` is a div that has ng-repeat attribute and influenced from a server request with `$http`, but I am not using `$httpBackend` so I don't know why this error happens.

Someone can figure out why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the only test you have in your app ? Because it could be invalidated by another test. If it's the case try to launch this test alone by writing 'fdescribe' instead of 'describe'

Comment: I have more tests in my app and I already run it with `fdescribe`. @Cyril