# AngularJS Karma Jasmine directive testing not rendering html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm learning Angular and I'm trying to run tests on directives with Karma Jasmine. However, it seems that the html template of the directive is not being rendered (e.g. ng-repeat and such is not being replaced/processed). I want to test whether the contents of the span with class `mdl-list__item-sub-title` is the expected rendered output.

My directive (`views/customersListDirective.html`) looks like this:

```
<!--Template for customer list directive-->
<ul class="demo-list-two mdl-list">
    <li ng-repeat="user in e.users" class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
        <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
        <span>{{user.nome}}</span>
        <span class="mdl-list__item-sub-title">{{user.valor | currency:"R$"}} at {{user.data | date:'dd-MMM'}}</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-info" ng-if="$first">VIP</span>
        <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons" ng-if="user.valor >= 100">star</i></a>
    </span>
    </li>
```

```
app.directive('customerList', [function(){
    return{
        templateUrl:"views/customersListDirective.html",
        restrict:"AE"
    };
}]);
```

And my test spec:

```
describe("Test Customer List Directive", function(){
    beforeEach(module('ex1'));
    beforeEach(module('templates'));
    var compile, scope, directiveElement;

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $templateCache, $rootScope){
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        directiveElement = angular.element('<div customer-List></div>');
        compile(directiveElement)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('basic test', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.users = [
                {
                    nome:"Alice",
                    data:"2016-05-02",
                    valor:100
                }
            ];
        });
        scope.$digest();

        var valor1 = directiveElement.find("<span class=\"mdl-list__item-sub-title\">");
        expect(valor1).toEqual('R$100 at 02-May');
    })
});
```

Finally the karma.conf file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'karmatest/angular.js',
      'karmatest/angular-mocks.js',
      'js/exampleCtrls.js',
      'js/exampleCtrlsSpec.js',
      'views/*.html'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'views/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        moduleName: 'templates'
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

As far as I can tell, I've done everything according to the examples/specs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214760/unit-testing-angularjs-directive-with-templateurl/16528985#16528985) and the other linked articles there. However, when running the test, the content of the `innerHtml` of the `directiveElement` variable, which I would expect to contain the rendered directive, contains only:

```
<div customer-list="" class="ng-scope"><!--Template for customer list directive-->
<ul class="demo-list-two mdl-list">
    <!-- ngRepeat: user in e.users -->
</ul></div>
```

And thus the test fails. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The stackoverflow link that you follow is outdated. Go to see the doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Comment: I've checked that too. There's no example of a directive with ng-repeat, for instance, which is what is not being compiled/rendered on my test

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like your ng-repeat is not defined properly

there doesn't seem to be any `e`

```
ng-repeat="user in e.users"
```

but you define in on your scope

```
scope.users = [
            {
                nome:"Alice",
                data:"2016-05-02",
                valor:100
            }
        ];
```