# Karma test on Angular directive returns unexpected request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple directive:

'use strict';

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('ngEmailMask', ngEmailMask);

function ngEmailMask() {

  var directive = {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      user: '@',
      host: '@'
    },
    template: '<a href="mailto:{{user}}@{{host}}">{{user}}@{{host}}</a>'
  };

  return directive;

}
```

I'm writing a Karma unit test to check the directive outputs the correct HTML. So far I've got this:

```
describe('ngEmailMask', function() {

  // Bindable members
  var $compile,
      $rootScope;

  // Load module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  // Bind injected references to local variables
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  // Verify service returns
  it('Replaces the tag with the correct HTML', function() {

    // Compile element
    var element = $compile('<ng-email-mask data-user="test" data-host="gmail.com"></ng-email-mask>')($rootScope);

    // Evaluate scope
    $rootScope.$digest();

    console.log(element.html());

  });

});
```

I've followed the example on the Angular website [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) but my example above returns an error:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET /app/home/home.html`

That path has nothing to do with the directive and may change (it's all to do with states and routing in UI Router that I'm using). So how do I test this directive without seeing these errors about different files?

Comment: Please share karma `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor` property

Comment: @R.J not sure what that is...

Comment: You can find it in karma config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must expect all XHR-calls (even templates) in a jasmine test. The easiest way is to add all templates to a templateCache before running the test.

See: [Unit Testing AngularJS directive with templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214760/unit-testing-angularjs-directive-with-templateurl)

Comment: Ah right. I've already created the template cache as part of my gulp build process so this sounds promising. I'll take a look through