# Why do I receive error ... unexpected request: GET /internalapi/quotes

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I've defined the following service in my angular app :

```
services.factory('MyService', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
       return {
           events : { loading : true },

           retrieveQuotes : function() {
               return Restangular.all('quotes').getList().then(function() {
                   return { hello: 'World' };
               });
           }
    };
}]);
```

and I'm writing the following spec to test it :

```
describe("MyService", function () {

    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
    beforeEach(module("restangular"));

    var $httpBackend, Restangular, ms;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _Restangular_, MyService) {
        ms = MyService;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        Restangular = _Restangular_;
    }));


    it("retrieveQuotes should be defined", function () {
        expect(ms.retrieveQuotes).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("retrieveQuotes should return array of quotes", function () {

        $httpBackend.whenGET("internalapi/quotes").respond({ hello: 'World' });
        ms.retrieveQuotes();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

});
```

Whenever I run the tests, the first test passes but the second test produces the error :

`Error: Unexpected request: GET /internalapi/quotes`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

It turned out I'd configured `Restangular` like so ... `RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/internalapi");`. But I was faking calls to `internalapi/quotes`. Notice the lack of the "/". Once I added the slash `/internalapi/quotes` all was good :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761045/jasmine-tests-angularjs-directives-with-templateurl   (I didn't flag as duplicate, because the problems seem different to an extent).

Comment: Please remember to mark your question as resolved, based on your edit it looks like it has been fixed. :)

Comment: It may be obvious to others, but in case it's not, these `expectMETHOD` calls expect you to pass in the full URL, not just the path, if you're calling external services.

Comment: Another way to avoid this whole difficulty (if a certain test doesn't need that much specificity) is to pass in a regular expression instead of a string.  E.g., $httpBackend.expectGET(/internalapi/) or $httpBackend.expect('GET', /quotes/)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to tell $httpBackend to expect a GET request.

```
describe("MyService", function () {

   beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
   beforeEach(module("restangular"));

   var Restangular, ms;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_Restangular_, MyService) {
        ms = MyService;

        Restangular = _Restangular_;
    }));


    it("retrieveQuotes should be defined", function () {
        expect(ms.retrieveQuotes).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("retrieveQuotes should return array of quotes", inject(function ($httpBackend) {

        $httpBackend.whenGET("internalapi/quotes").respond({ hello: 'World' });

        //expect a get request to "internalapi/quotes"
        $httpBackend.expectGET("internalapi/quotes");

        ms.retrieveQuotes();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));

});
```

Alternatively you can put your `respond()` on your `expectGET()`. I prefer to put my `whenGET()` statements in a `beforeEach()` that way I do not have to define the response within every test.

```
        //expect a get request to "internalapi/quotes"
        $httpBackend.expectGET("internalapi/quotes").respond({ hello: 'World' });

        ms.retrieveQuotes();
        $httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even if I add ```$httpBackend.expectGET("internalapi/quotes");```, I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: That should work. Just a guess but try injecting the `$httpBackend` directly into your test. I will update the post to show this.

Comment: No, same thing. I've looked at lots of examples and I agree, I appear to be doing it correctly, but no joy unfortunately.

Comment: Oh dear, I feel very stupid. I've worked it out now, it was simple. I had configured ```Restangular``` thus ```RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/internalapi");``` and expected a call to```internalapi/quotes```. Notice the missing slash. My bad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its happens, at least one of us noticed it.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to make unit test on $resource working using absolute path? I call the $resource in my service using an absolute path because is crossorigin call. I'm trying this for days but the result is the same "Unexpected request: GET". Did anyone succeed, I see that is working  correctly with simple $http but not with $resource? Thanks!

Comment: @SimonLomax Almost 7 years later I have to thank you. Just spent hours learning all of the ins and outs of $httpBackend, and it turns out I had a trailing slash before my query param in the URL :facepalm:

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem as you guys. My solution was to add a '/' at the start of the URL-parameter of the .expectGET. Using your example:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET("/internalapi/quotes").respond({ hello: 'world'})
```

Best of luck