# Angular: Error: Unexpected request: GET

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a simple controller to get some information from a server but, I don't know why is not working.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var InvestorProfileApp=angular.module('InvestorProfileApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache',"xeditable", "ngMockE2E"])
      InvestorProfileApp.controller('InvestorProfileCtrl', controller);

  function controller($scope, $filter, $http) {
    /*//$scope.photo_url = direccion+":"+puerto+localStorage.getItem(usuario);*/
    $http.get(direccion + ":" + puerto + "/usr/1")
    .success(function(data) {
    })
    .error(function(error){
      console.log("Error: "+error);
    });
    $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
    $scope.Account=
      {
        cashBalance: '$1,550',
        equityBalance: '$620',
        total: '$2,100'
      }
    ;

    $scope.RPerformance=
      {
        percentile:'70th',         
      }
    ;
    $scope.GralInfo=[
      {
      }
    ];

    $scope.user = {
      lives:  'New York, NY',
        employer: 'Nexxus Capital',
        job: 'Financial Analyst',
        studied:'Oxford University',
        major:'Finance',
        risk: 'High'
    }; 

    $scope.saveUser = function() {
      // $scope.user already updated!
      return $http.post('/saveUser', $scope.user).error(function(err) {
        if(err.field && err.msg) {
          // err like {field: "name", msg: "Server-side error for this username!"} 
          $scope.editableForm.$setError(err.field, err.msg);
        } else { 
          // unknown error
          $scope.editableForm.$setError('name', 'Unknown error!');
        }
      });
    };

    $scope.goto = function(page){
      $scope.currNavItem = page;
    };  
  };
})();
```

I used this code in other controllers and it works fine, ut with this I get the next error

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://35.161.59.162:4040/usr/1
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1420)
    at sendReq (angular.js:11517)
    at serverRequest (angular.js:11227)
    at processQueue (angular.js:15961)
    at angular.js:15977
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17045)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17337)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1749)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4665)
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147606/why-do-i-receive-error-unexpected-request-get-internalapi-quotes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some tests for this controller and these tests fail because of unexpected request. You should mock them using

```
$httpBackend.expectGET("/usr/1");
```

Comment: I don't know how to use $httpBackend.expectGET("/usr/1"); Do you have an example? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I'm not doing tests of anything. The code I posted is all I have.

Comment: But you have `angular-mocks.js` - it' used for testing