# AngularJS+Jasmine - Get a controller scope write in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, jasmine, directive

I'm kinda new in AngularJS unit testing and I'm having some troubles to test a controller method that was written in a directive.

This is my **directive.js**

```
app.directive('formLogin', ['AuthService', function(AuthService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: utils.baseUrl + 'partials/_home-form-login.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $http, $location) {
            $scope.visible = false;
            $scope.showForm = function () {
                $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

And here goes my **unit-test.js**

```
describe('formLogin ctrl', function () {
    var element, scope, compile;

    beforeEach(module('Application'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        element = angular.element('<form-login></form-login>');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = $compile(element)($scope);       
    }));

    it('Test', function() {
        expect(scope.visible).toBe(false);
    })
});
```

And by doing this the "scope.visible" come as undefined.

There are some way to take the $scope from my controller that assumes in "scope" variable the "visible" property and the "showForm" method?

Comment: Have you decelerated isolated scope? You can have access to it by calling `element.isolateScope()`

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/12/05/unit-testing-angularjs-directive/)
 it looks like you might need to do a `scope.$digest();`

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a couple problems:

1. `compile = $compile(element)($scope);` -- here, `$scope` is undefined. It should be `compile = $compile(element)(scope);`
2. As mentioned by smk, you need to digest your scope to finish the directive creation process

   - This is especially important because you are using `templateUrl`. When you just use a locally-defined `template`, as Krzysztof does in his example, you can get by with skipping this step.

You will probably notice that when you add `scope.$digest()` you will get a different problem about an unexpected GET request. This is because Angular is trying to GET the templateUrl, and during testing all HTTP requests must be configured / expected manually. You might be tempted to inject `$httpBackend` and do something like `$httpBackend.whenGet(/partials\//).respond('<div/>');` but you will end up with problems that way.

The better way to accomplish this is to inject the template `$templateCache` -- Karma has a pre-processor to do this for you, or you can do it manually. There have been other StackOverflow questions you can read about this, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761045/jasmine-tests-angularjs-directives-with-templateurl).

I've modified your example to manually insert a simple template into the `$templateCache` as a simple example [in this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tD0bXF3Sfl9qbrcWKIAI).

You should take a look into Karma's `html2js` pre-processor to see if it can do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your directive **hasn't isolated scope**, you can call methods from directive controller and test how it impacts to scope values.

```
describe('myApp', function () {
    var scope
      , element
    ;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('Directive: formLogin', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = angular.element('<form-login></form-login>');
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }));

        it('.showForm() – changes value of $scope.visible', function() {
            expect(scope.visible).toBe(false);
            scope.showForm();
            expect(scope.visible).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/L2rBV/1/